# Closure property bad access in swift (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, initialization, closures

I have the `Test` class with `button_action` optional closure:

```
class Test : CustomViewFromXib {
    var button_action : (() -> ())?
    @IBAction func button_pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let action = button_action {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I use this class:

```
 let test_view = Test(frame: CGRect.nullRect)
 self.view.addSubview(test_view)
 test_view.button_action = {
    () -> () in
    print("test")
 }
```

I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at line:

```
test_view.button_action = {
    () -> () in
    print("test")
}
```

I don't know why, because I just want to set initial value. Is it possible to do it that way?

## UPDATE:

I understood, that no one property or method can't be called from my object. Not only closures, but Strings (for example) too.

## UPDATE 2:

This is my little example of code that reproduces the problem. I think I have a problem with initializers...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d8fvxm0es9b5n4/TestInit.zip

(XCode 6 Beta 5)

Comment: I created a test project, with similar code and it works for me - but I added the Test View in interface builder (to connect a button).  So I would say it's nothing to do with setting the button_action variable, or the types of the closure

Comment: Hmm.. I tried to create property `test : String = "xxx"` and access it by test_view.test = "zzz" and it doesn't work too. Also I added method test() and I can't call it.

Answer (score 0):

Write code

```
let test_view = Test(frame: CGRect.nullRect)
 self.view.addSubview(test_view)
 test_view.button_action = {
    () -> () in
    print("test")
 }
```

instead of

```
let test_view = Test(frame: CGRect.nullRect)
 self.view.addSubview(test_view)
 test_view.button_action = { [unowned self]
    () -> () in
    print("test")
 }
```

Here is exact detail theoretical answer 
[Shall we always use [unowned self] inside closure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift) 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html