# How to store a Closure completion handler to call later?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, closures

I'm working on converting this [In-App Purchase tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) into Swift and have come across an issue trying to save the completion handler. We need to store this completion handler so that it can be called later. I cannot figure out how to store a copy of the closure from the arguments. Specifically, I believe I need to copy it but Xcode states this object doesn't have a copy function.

I've defined it like so:

```
typealias RequestProductsCompletionHandler = (success: Bool, products: NSArray) -> Void
```

Here I declare a property for it:

```
var completionHandler: RequestProductsCompletionHandler?
```

Then this is where I need to store the passed in completion handler into my property:

```
func requestProductsWithCompletionHandler(completionBlock: RequestProductsCompletionHandler) -> Void {
    //self.completionHandler = completionBlock.copy() //problem: RequestProductsCompletionHandler does not have a member named copy
}
```

This is how it was done in the Obj-C tutorial:

```
typedef void (^RequestProductsCompletionHandler)(BOOL success, NSArray * products);

RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
}
```

And later it is used like so:

```
_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
_completionHandler = nil;
```

EDIT: I've removed the .copy() to prevent the error (also had to make the NSArray optional so that I can set it to nil later). My question is, will it work as expected without explicitly copying it? I don't believe it will because [Apple stated closures are reference types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). **This will store a reference to the original closure which I don't want to do. How does one enforce a copy?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It will work as expected.

Whenever you call `requestProductsWithCompletionHandler` you create a closure and pass it to that function.
And as you mentioned, when you set `completionHandler` you actually set it to be a reference to the given closure.

In Objective C, to store the block as ivar you had to copy a block. That's because a block first residing on the stack memory where it was defined. And copy moved it to the heap memory so it can be used

Comment: I had the exact problem, so thanks. While researching the answer, I came across this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56 in the Swift documentation. I tried adding the `lazy` variable, but it gave me an error (there is no initializer for the variable). Will this cause a reference cycle?

Comment: @coopersita As described in the document you mentioned, you should define 'capture list'  for the closure and specify that 'self' is unowned.  `{ [unowned self] in ...}`

Comment: Thanks, @tsafrir, I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift