# Do I need [unowned self] or [weak self] in this closure?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xfc3158)
    fadeBackground()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.fadeTime, target: self, selector: Selector("fadeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func fadeBackground(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.fadeTime, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: {
        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme.count)))
        self.view.backgroundColor = CONSTANTS.MainColorScheme[randomIndex]
    }) { (stuff Bool) -> Void in
    }
}
```

I'm a little confused about why I need to use [unowned self].  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift), I should only use [unowned self] if *I don't care that self is still around when the closure is called*.  But I never see why that would ever be the case. Why would I *not* care if self is around?  I want self to be around when the closure is called -- that's why I wrote the code there.

Do I need unowned self in the `animations` closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you don't need to use capture list, because both closures are `UIView` and not retained by `self`. The retain cycle is not created in your example.