# What is the correct way of use strongSelf in swift?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

In Objective-C in non-trivial blocks I noticed usage of weakSelf/strongSelf.

What is the correct way of usage strongSelf in Swift?
Something like:

```
if let strongSelf = self {
  strongSelf.doSomething()
}
```

So for each line containing self in closure I should add strongSelf check?

```
if let strongSelf = self {
  strongSelf.doSomething1()
}

if let strongSelf = self {
  strongSelf.doSomething2()
}
```

Is there any way to make aforesaid more elegant?

Comment: There's nothing special about `strongSelf` here.  It's just a variable name.  Perhaps add the Objective-C code you're hoping to replicate?  What you're doing here is no different from simply `self?.doSomething()`

Comment: Please check this question there is `[unowned self]` in swift : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift and https://dhoerl.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/i-finally-figured-out-weakself-and-strongself/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using `strongSelf` is a way to check that `self` is not equal to nil. When you have a closure that may be called at some point in the future, it is important to pass a `weak` instance of self so that you do not create a retain cycle by holding references to objects that have been deinitialized.

```
{[weak self] () -> void in 
      if let strongSelf = self {
         strongSelf.doSomething1()
      }
}
```

Essentially you are saying if self no longer exists do not hold a reference to it and do not execute the action on it.

Comment: You can also substitute `if let` with `guard let` here to avoid another nesting (indentation) level: `guard let strongSelf = self else { return }`

Answer (score 16):

### Swift 4.2

```
guard let self = self else { return }
```

Ref: https://benscheirman.com/2018/09/capturing-self-with-swift-4-2/
Ref2: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

Answer (score 7):

another way to use `weak self`without using `strongSelf`

```
{[weak self] () -> void in 
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      self.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: I love this BUT be careful. Chris Lattner has specifically stated this is a compiler bug https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160118/007425.html

Answer (score 5):

Your use of `strongSelf` appears to be directed at only calling the `doSomethingN()` method if `self` is not nil.  Instead, use optional method invocation as the preferred approach:

```
self?.doSomethingN()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `self` in your closure it is automatically used as strong.

There is also way to use as `weak` or `unowned` if you trying to avoid a retain cycles. It is achieved by passing [unowned self] or [weak self] before closure's parameters.