# Confused on closure strong reference cycle?

Tags: swift, reference, closures, automatic-ref-counting, strong-references

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name : String
    let text: String?

    //Declaring a lazy variable that has a strong reference to this closure
    lazy var asHTML: Void -> String = {
        //Optional binding here
        if let text = self.text {
             return "<\(self.name)>\(text)<\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) >"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil){
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}
```

My Question is: Why is the closure declared Lazy, I know it has something to do with `self` not being known in the closure, but isn't that the same case for the `init` method where `self` hasn't been created?

Secondly,Where exactly is the strong reference cycle in this code example, is it `self` that strongly references to `asHTML`, if so where is the second part of the strong referencing that causes the cycle?

Third, Why is the constant `text` property an optional when constants cannot change value(from `nil` to a value and back to `nil`)?

Lastly, What does it mean to have the parameter `text: String? = nil` in the `init` method when the `init` method is used to accept parameters sent by the user?

Sorry for this long question, I'm just confused on the closure strong reference cycle....although I do understand strong reference cycles between class properties and class instances.

Answer (score 1):

**1**

`lazy` is used for attributes that are only created when called upon. So before you call `myClass.myLazyAttribute` it will not take up any space. This also means that it will init after the class has initialised, which can be very useful.

In this case `lazy` is used to get access to `self`, like you stated, because `self` is not available until the instance has been initialised.

**2**

[The apple doc from where code is.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48])

Closures capture the values used in them. In this case it captures `self`.
It does not create a Strong Reference Cycle between class A and class B, but between itself and a closure. It makes a lot more sense if you imagine that the operation inside the closure takes a very long time. During the execution something else has happened and you want to deinit the instance. But the closure has captured `self` and it will keep the instance alive until it is done.

By using `[unowned self] in` you can again deinit the instance while the closure is running. Although this will crash your app.

good info on this specific use : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)

> In the specific case of a closure, you just need to realize that any variable that is referenced inside of it, gets "owned" by the closure. As long as the closure is around, those objects are guaranteed to be around. The only way to stop that ownership, is to do the [unowned self] or [weak self].

**What a Strong Reference Cycle in essence is:**

- you have an instance of a class
- the instance has a reference count higher than 0
- there is no longer a reference to the instance available to your program.

Or even shorter: the reference count of the instance is higher than the number of accessible references.

In this case the reference count of `self` goes up by 1 because it is captured by the closure. We can not access that reference because we can not say something like: `closure.selfAttribute`, so we can not set that to `nil`. Only when the closure is finished will the reference count go down by 1 again.

**3**

It is an **optional constant**, but it's initial value is set in the init method of the class. So it can receive a value in the init method, but it will be immutable. This is called a **late init**.

**4**

This is a function parameter with a default value.

```
func someFunction(myParamWithDefaultValue : Int = 10) {
    print(myParamWithDefaultValue)
}

someFunction() // 10
someFunction(5) // 5
```

Comment: Note that not just `weak` but also `unowned` isn't a strong reference

Comment: ok now I have a question, If I create an instance of the `HTMLElement` class, the documentation says that there will be a strong reference cycle, I understand half of what they mean.......The closure uses self.name and self.text which "captures" self and makes a strong reference to instances of the `HTMLElement` class.....now how is there a strong reference FROM the instance back to the closure??

Comment: @Ali then I would need to know how the other side looks like. Also where is this code from. You mention documentation, so is this a tutorial, or a framework?

Comment: This is straight from the Apple documentation: {\[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48]

Comment: All the way down to the Closure strong reference cycle example

Comment: @Ali updated. The apple doc example is stupid. They explain the technical side but not the practical side. It makes more sense if you can imagine when and how this might be a problem.

Comment: ok so I shouldn't worry about this too much, I'm a beginning swift programmer and plan to build iOS apps which has gotten me overwhelmed with all the info I have to learn, so you think I should just get the basic info and drive right in?

Comment: The thing is I'm not understanding how an instance could point to the closure and strongly reference it?? I know how the closure is currently pointing to the instance because it has captured `self` which is aka an instance of the class.....

Comment: @Ali check this article out: http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift, it helped me understand the semantics.

Comment: @RMenke, "Only when the closure is finished will the reference count go down by 1 again." Does it mean that as soon as the closure was executed, both self and the closure will get deallocated? You can imagine a uialertaction with a closure capturing self.

Comment: @Fawkes sorry for the late reply. If you capture `self` in a closure and this closure is a long operation (network request) and there are no longer any other reference to `self` when the operation is finished `self` will get deallocated.