# How do I randomise a repeatAction count?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a SKAction that repeats forever that releases a random number of objects in a wave but I can't seems to find a way to randomise the count of a SKAction.repeatAction each time it's repeated in the SKAction.repeatActionForver. Anyone know a solution to my issue?

let objectSet = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([addObject, objectDelay]), count: ***random value***))

```
let setDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0, withRange: 1.0)

let objectDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.6, withRange: 0.4)

let objectSet = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([addObject, objectDelay]), count: *Trying to get a random value*))

objectLayerNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([objectSet, setDelay])))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UPPER_BOUND))`.

Then

```
let objectSet = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([addObject, objectDelay]), count: random))
```

You could also do a range with an upper and lower bound.

```
let random = LOWER_BOUND + arc4random_uniform(UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND + 1)
```

**EDIT**

You can use recursion. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34052886/5181636)

```
let setDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0, withRange: 1.0)
let objectDelay = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.6, withRange: 0.4)

func repeat() {

    let random = LOWER_BOUND + arc4random_uniform(UPPER_BOUND - LOWER_BOUND + 1)

    let objectSet = SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([addObject, objectDelay]), count: random))

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([
        objectSet, objectDelay,SKAction.runBlock({
            [unowned self] in self.repeat()
        })
    ])

    objectLayerNode.runAction(sequence)
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a random let with a upper and lower bound but it seems to only randomise the count once and keeps the same value for each repeatForever loop of the repeatAction.

Comment: It seems to still only get a random count at the start and keep that value. Eg: repeatAction count gives 5, 5, 5, 5, 5... in each repeat not a random value like 5, 7, 10, 14, 4...

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks Caleb