# Using 'self' on RxSwift closures... What about instance methods as param?

Tags: memory, swift2, rx-swift, retain-cycle, retaincount

In [other stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003355/weak-self-in-rxswift-closures), it was emphasized that the capture `[weak self]` should be used for closures that aren't owned by the class because `self` could be nil before the closure completes. An alternative when the closure is owned by the class itself is `[unowned self]`.

My question is do I need to use `[unowned self]` when the function I pass as a parameter is an instance method of the current class?

### Example

```
import RxSwift

class Person {
    var name = "Default name"

    class func getPersons() -> Observable<Person> {
        // ...
    }


}

class MyController: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    // I know this right
    func unownedDisplayPeople() {

        Person.getPersons()
            .subscribeNext { [unowned self ] person in
                self.displayName(person)
            }
            .addDisposableToBag(disposeBag)
    }

    // But what about this?
    func whatAboutThisDisplayPeople() {

        Person.getPersons()
            .subscribeNext(displayName)
            .addDisposableToBag(disposeBag)
    }

    // Or this?
    func orThisDisplayPeople() {

        Person.getPersons()
            .subscribeNext(self.displayName)
            .addDisposableToBag(disposeBag)
    }

    func displayName(person: Person) {
        print("Person name is \(person.name)")
    }
}
```

If I still need to think about the reference counting when I just pass an instance method, how do I do it? Where do i put the `[unowned self]`? Or is it considered `[unowned self]` already when I just pass the instance method?

Comment: Related: [How to remove strong reference cycle from closure from method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39899051/2976878)

Comment: How you can do using [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt) — [example](https://twitter.com/abdurahimjauzee/status/1005157382643699716)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, passing an instance method to `subscribeNext` **will** retain `self`. To be more generic, storing a reference to an instance method will increase the retain count of the instance.

```
let instance = ReferenceType()
print(CFGetRetainCount(instance)) // 1

let methodReference = instance.method
print(CFGetRetainCount(instance)) // 2
```

The only solution here is do what you have done in `unownedDisplayPeople`.

```
let instance = ReferenceType()
print(CFGetRetainCount(instance)) // 1

let methodReference = { [unowned instance] in instance.method() }
print(CFGetRetainCount(instance)) // 1
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this tomahh. I'm just bothered by the syntax cause it doesn't look pretty at all. :( But I guess I'll have to make do with it to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Yeah, I hate it too. Maybe there's a way we could create a `subscribeWeaklyNext` version of `subscribeNext` that does not change the retain count...

Comment: So, I fiddled around a bit in the swift playground and hit a wall. Closures cannot be made `weak` as it only applies to class and class-bound protocols. I guess self is capture before the function call (that accepts the closure) is made. Seems like we are stuck with this "non-optimal" syntax :/

Comment: Additional reading: http://blog.stablekernel.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures