# Please help me understand these lines of code

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
@IBAction func addName(_ sender: AnyObject) { 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name",   message: "Add a new name",  preferredStyle: .alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",  style: .default) {
        [unowned self] action in
        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first, 
            let nameToSave = textField.text else { 
                return
        }
        self.names.append(nameToSave)
        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    }
```

I can understand most parts of the code, except the following lines:

```
[unowned self] action in
guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
```

I would write the code in the following way:

```
@IBAction func addName(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name",   message: "Add a new name",  preferredStyle: .alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",  style: .default) {
    let nameToSave = textField.text
    self.names.append(nameToSave)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

What's wrong with my code?
What's the use of `[unowned self] action in` and the following `guard let` code in that case?
What dose `alert.textFields?.first` mean ?

Comment: You are asking about two completely separate lines of code, not one. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift refer this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `saveAction` has a closure block at the end which is basically what will happen when the save action is triggered. Inside closures, you need to reference the variables with `self`. When you use `self` it creates a strong reference with the closure. The `[unowned self]` basically means tells not to create a strong reference with the closure.

For the next part, the `guard` keyword is used to ensure that a value is not nil. Here, the `alert.textFields?.first` is an optional textfield. So, if you do `alert.textFields!.first!.text!` and the textField turns out to be nil, your app will crash. To prevent this, the `guard` keyword is used. If the value in it turns out to be `nil`, the control will enter the `else` block and return skipping all the below code.

Have a look at [this](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift) article if you want to read more about strong and weak references.