# Is method closure retaining the instance in swift?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting

In swift, I can use instance methods as closures, for example, assigning the method to a callback

```
self.someView.someCallback = self.doSomething
```

So, is `self` strongly referenced here in `self.doSomething`? Does the line above create a reference loop?

Comment: Check out this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift

Comment: @DejanSkledar: None of the answers to that question is applicable to mine.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible scenarios based upon your code snippet:

1. If `doSomething` is a instance method of `self`, then, yes, that line establishes a strong reference. Remember that [Closures are Reference Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID104). You can easily confirm this and is easily confirmed empirically. Consider:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       var foo: (() -> Void)?

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           foo = bar

           foo?()
       }

       func bar() { ... }
   }
   ```

   If I present and dismiss this view controller three times, and then use Xcode’s “Debug Memory Graph”, [image: debug memory graph], I will see those three instances still lingering in memory (on the left) and if I select one, it will show me the strong reference cycle visually in the center panel:

   [image]

   And because I used the “Malloc stack” feature, on the right panel I can see precisely where the lingering strong reference is, namely in `viewDidLoad` where I set that closure.
2. However, if `doSomething` is not a function, but rather is a closure, then that line, itself, does not establish a strong reference, but rather it becomes a question of whether the closure, itself, refers to `self` and, if it does, whether there is a `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` capture list or not. For more information, see [Strong Reference Cycles for Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID56).

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a retain cycle, you need to have a strong reference on each direction, i.e.:

> Object A strongly references Object B
>
> Object B strongly references Object A

Assuming `self` in the code you shared is a *View Controller*, and assuming `someView` is a strong reference to a view, we could say that:

> Object A (View Controller) strongly references Object B (Some View)

Now if Object B (Some View) has a strong reference back to the View Controller, you will have a retain cycle.

Assuming `doSomething` is a method in your ViewController, and not a closure, you **will have a retain cycle**

An easy way to check this, is by implementing `deinit` in both your *Some View* and your *View Controller*, like so:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var someView: CustomView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someView = CustomView(frame: view.frame)
        someView?.someCallback = doSomething
    }

    func doSomething() {
    }

    deinit {
        print(#function)
    }
}

final class CustomView: UIView {
    var someCallback: (() -> Void)?

    deinit {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

You will see that the `print`s on `deinit` are never printed out in the console. However changing the way you assign `someCallback` to:

```
someView?.someCallback = { [weak self] in
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

will cause `deinit` to run, thus breaking the retain cycle

**Edit:**

<strike>Or even, as an alternative:</strike>

```
weak var weakSelf = self
someView?.someCallback = weakSelf?.doSomething
```

(**Even though this is using a weak reference, because this expression is evaluated at the time the assignment of `someCallback` is performed, not at the time it is executed, this will still become a `strong` reference**) - Thanks [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, declare a closure type variable, and would like to assign a func to it, prevent from the retain issue,
just do as follow, search the answer for all day long, eager to share:

`self.someView.someCallback = { 
    [unowned self] in self.doSomething() 
}`