# Swift Combine - How to get a Publisher that delivers events for every character change of UITextField's text property

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, combine

I noticed that

```
textField.publisher(for: \.text)
```

delivers events when editing finishes, but not for every character/editing change. How do I get a Publisher, that sends evens for every change?
In ReactiveSwift it would be

```
textField.reactive.continousTextValues()
```

And in RxSwift it would be just ([How do you get a signal every time a UITextField text property changes in RxSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633173/how-do-you-get-a-signal-every-time-a-uitextfield-text-property-changes-in-rxswif))

```
textField.rx.text
```

Approaches I took:

- checking the `publisher(for:options:)` method, but there are no appropriate options for the desired outcome.
- adding a target/action `textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(theTextFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)` ([UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event))
- doing essentially the same as the previous step by connecting the action via interface builder, both leading to extra work and cluttered code.
- Watching the 2019 WWDC videos about Combine. They were not dealing with textfields, but using `@Published` variables instead, hiding were the values actually came from - (or did I miss something?).

I have no clue at the moment, how to do this and I feel the tendency to go back to ReactiveSwift, but I wanted to ask you, before taking this step backwards.

Comment: Why don't you use `TextField` instead of `UITextField`? That updates its `text` binding on each character change.

Comment: There's a good chance OP doesn't (want to) use SwiftUI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple didn't add publishers for this to UIKit and because UIControl doesn't implement KVO the `publisher(for:)` publisher doesn't work quite as expected. If you're okay with adding a dependency to your project there are a couple of good UIControl publishers [here](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineCocoa).

Alternatively, you could implement your own publisher that does this, or subscribe to textfield changes the old school way.

Answer (score 16):

In case of a UITextField you can use this extension:

```
  extension UITextField {
    func textPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: self)
            .map { ($0.object as? UITextField)?.text  ?? "" }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
  }
```

use as: textField.textPublisher()

Answer (score 6):

If this is what you are looking for, I guess `UITextField` emits both notifications and controlevents, so you can achieve that by listening to notifications for example:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var textField: UITextField!

    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textFieldPublisher = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField)
            .map( {
                ($0.object as? UITextField)?.text
            })
        
        textFieldPublisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                print("UITextField.text changed to: \(value)")
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this was your actual goal.

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a custom Publisher for your needs. For example, here I've created TextField publisher, that wraps textFieldDidChange action for textField and sends String after each character entered/deleted! Please, copy the link, SO doesn't parse it:

https://github.com/DmitryLupich/Combine-UIKit/blob/master/CombineCustomPublishers/%20Publishers/TextFieldPubisher.swift