# Why would I ever use unowned self?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The following pattern happens a lot in iOS apps:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myModel = MyModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myModel.foo() { [***] in
            // use self here
        }
    }
}

class MyModel {
    public func foo(complete: () -> Void) {
        // do something
        complete()
    }
}
```

The consensus is to use either `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` in place of the `[***]`, unowned when you can guarantee that self will not be nil at the time of completion and weak when you're not sure the reference will still be valid.
What I don't understand is why I would ever risk using unowned, maybe I'm sure that right now the reference will never be nil, but that can change in the future. I could also have overlooked an edge-case, mistakes happen. I could just as easily always use weak, and put a guard at the top of the closure to be able to use self without a ! or ?.
What is the use of unowned? Is it faster than weak+guard? Is it syntactic sugar? It seems to go against Swift's philosophy of protecting the developer against common mistakes that can cause crashes.

Comment: I don't know swift very well, but in other languages, concepts like this `[unowned]` are very important for interfacing with other languages like C which lack reference counting.  Though why one would use it in the setting you present is beyond me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`unowned` has a marginal performance advantage over `weak` because the runtime doesn't have to keep track of the reference to turn it into `nil` when the object goes away.

In respect of retain cycles (well, strong reference cycles), neither `weak` nor `unowned` creates a strong reference (in pre ARC terms, neither increments the retain count) so there is no danger of a reference cycle, in fact, that is why you need to specify `weak` or `unowned` for `self` in closures.

Also, with `unowned` you can use the reference as a non optional, so you don't have to put any code in the closure to unwrap it.

I always use `weak` unless there is a really good performance reason not to.

NB in your code, I do not think either is necessary because the closure is not escaping i.e. The reference to it taken in the function call `foo` does not persist after the end of `foo`'s scope.

Comment: How about  retain cycle in both case ? , is it relevant there  in difference ?

Comment: As per me  for weak self there is not a single possibility for Retain cycle but i don't know about unowned

Comment: @JonSnow `unowned` is not a strong reference either.

Comment: "*because the runtime doesn't have to keep track of the reference to turn it into nil when the object goes away*" – that's actually not how `weak` references work in the Swift runtime (although it is indeed w/ the Obj-C runtime). Basically, when a weak reference is formed to an object, the object gains a "side table" that tracks its reference counts (and keeps a ptr to the object). A weak reference then points to the this side table. Even after the object is deallocated, weak references still point to that side table...

Comment: ... On loading a weak reference, the strong retain count is checked; if it's zero, then `nil` is returned. Then when the weak retain count reaches zero, the side table is deallocated. This blog post is a good read on the subject: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html. Although that all being said, `unowned` references will still likely have a marginal performance advantage due the fact that `weak` references will require an additional dereference (from side table to object).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for that, it was most illuminating. I think my statement is still true. The runtime still tracks weak references by keeping a retain count for them and there's still a performance hit caused by the extra indirection through the side table.

Comment: @JeremyP The runtime keeps a reference count for them, yes, but it doesn't track the addresses of the weak variables *themselves* unlike in Obj-C, and so therefore cannot zero them out immediately upon on the strong retain count reaching zero ("turn it into `nil` when the object goes away"). Additionally. I don't even *think* that the runtime *lazily* zeroes out weak references (on loading from them); it just waits for the reference to be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using `unowned` adds to the risk than using weak self. Mistakes do happen and one example of it would be starting an API call in a view controller, let it wait for the response to arrive and suddenly popping that view controller may cause it to get deallocated (If there are no strong references to it). By the time when the response arrives, our view controller object would be gone, and our app will crash on our face. It is up to us  to decide which one to use in which place.

As **Jeremy** pointed out, `unowned` does not have the responsibility to keep track of the reference count, so it has ever so slight performance advantage over strong and weak.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Swit Programming Guide: Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

> An unowned reference is expected to always have a value. As a result, ARC never sets an unowned reference’s value to nil, which means that unowned references are defined using nonoptional types.

In short, `weak` are optionals, where `unowned` are not.

Comment: But why? It seems using unowned only introduces risk without gain. I would much rather play it safe and always use weak, with a guard self != nil at the top.

Comment: @kevin If you have a precondition in your program that object A *must not* outlive object B, then it's perfectly reasonable for object A to keep an `unowned`, rather than `weak`, reference to object B. If the precondition is broken, you probably don't want your application to silently continue in an invalid state; you want it to trap, so you can fix the bug. It's not a case of risk, it's a case of ensuring you have a well-formed program.

Comment: @Hamish +1 That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

An simple example of using unowned reference in navigation controller:

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var navigatinRightBarItemsCount: Int = { [unowned self] in
        guard let navigationController = self.navigationController else { return 0 }
        guard let topItem = navigationController.navigationBar.topItem else { return 0 }
        guard let rightBarButtonItems = topItem.rightBarButtonItems else { return 0 }
        return rightBarButtonItems.count
        }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("Navigation bar right side items count: ", navigationRightBarItemsCount)
    }
}
```

This means that RegisterViewController must be initialized than we can safely get **self.** navigationController and from here to get items count. If you try to make it as [weak self], XCode will complain because self(viewcontroller) can be nil, so we must use unowned.

Another example with UIBarButtonItem

```
lazy final private var filterNavigationBarItem: UIBarButtonItem = { [unowned self] in
    return UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "filter_icon"),
                           style: .plain,
                           target: self,
                           action: #selector(segueToFilterJobs))
    }()
```

What we see here? See the target which stands for "*The object that receives the action message.*" which means that object that receives the action message can not be nil and must be initialized.

A very nice explanation from [drewag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661853/drewag) in [this article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift)

> The only time where you really want to use [unowned self] or [weak
>   self] is when you would create a strong reference cycle. A strong
>   reference cycle is when there is a loop of ownership where objects end
>   up owning each other (maybe through a third party) and therefore they
>   will never be deallocated because they are both ensuring that each
>   other stick around.