# How to prevent leak in closure swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, closures

I have successfully implemented a closure in class to get filtered contacts from my phonebook but when I call this closure it creates a leak, I tested it in Xcode instrument tool.

See my implementation,

```
class CR: NSObject {

 func GetAllSBUser(handler:@escaping (Array<SBUserModel>?, Error?) -> ()) {
    CRBlock = handler

    if self.AllUSersModels.count>0 {
       self.CRBlock(self.AllUSersModels, nil)
    } else {
        self.CRBlock(nil, err)
    }}}
```

I use this method in another class, see my implementation.

> I also have a global instance in my app delegate like this
>
> let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

```
class friendsVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.app.cri?.AllSBFriends(handler: { (SBfriendsUIDs, error) in

            if error == nil{

                // Do something with list

            } else{ self.friendsCountLbl.text = "Friends \(0)" }
        })
    }
}
```

In class friendsVC, this method produces a leak. How can I remove it?
Should I use [unowned self] or weak? [unowned self] or weak may create a crash in some special cases of retain cycle. 
Please suggest me, how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `weak` modifier for closures where your will be using `self`

```
self.app.cri?.AllSBFriends(handler: { [weak self] (SBfriendsUIDs, error) in

        if error == nil{

            // Do something with list

        } else{ self?.friendsCountLbl.text = "Friends \(0)" }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, @Reinier Melian for your answer. could you please explain why I should not use unowned?

Comment: @HarendraTiwari, basically you should use unowned only when your are really sure that this variable [self] will be not nil at the time that closure is executed, normally I use [weak self] all the time and check self nullability, check this answer for further information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift

Comment: Great, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Harendra,

As conveyed by @Reinier use the below code like below.

self.app.cri?.AllSBFriends(handler: { [weak self] (SBfriendsUIDs, error) in

```
    if error == nil{

        // Do something with list

    } else{ self?.friendsCountLbl.text = "Friends \(0)" }
})
```

*IMP*:- Also implementation inside **CRBlock** func should be inside @autoreleasepool{ 
  //Implementation of CRBlock func 
}