# How Unowned reference works with capture variables in Swift

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, unowned-references

There are a lot of tutorials on ARC. But I am not understanding the clear working of unowned or weak as how the reference captured variables becomes null.

Apple Document :

> Define a capture in a closure as an unowned reference when the closure
>   and the instance it captures will always refer to each other, and will
>   always be deallocated at the same time.

```
class RetainCycle {
        var closure: (() -> Void)!
        var string = "Hello"

        init() {
            closure = { [unowned self] in
                self.string = "Hello, World!"
            }
        }
    }
```

the closure refers to self within its body (as a way to reference self.string), the closure captures self, which means that it holds a strong reference back to the RetainCycle instance. A strong reference cycle is created between the two. By unowned its breaking reference cycle.

But I  want to understand which scenario **both will not be mutually** deallocated at the same time and Unowned self becomes null just want to crash it.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320347/shall-we-always-use-unowned-self-inside-closure-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

As I get, You ask How self can be null while closue is running. If I get this right I can give you a quite similar example this that I have seen before.

I wrote an extension to UIImageView that download image from given link and set itself like this.

```
public extension UIImageView{
  func downloadImage(link: String){
    let url = URL(string:link)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ [unowned self]
      if let image = UIImage(data: data){
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
          self.image = image
        }
      }
    }
    task.start()
  }
}
```

But there was a problem. Downloading an image is a background task. I set completion method to UrlSession and increased its reference count. So, my closure remains even if imageView is deaollecated.

So What happens if I close my `viewController` that holds my `UIImageView`, before download completed. It crashes because of `imageView` is deallocated but closure still remains and tries to reach its `image` property. As I get, you want to learn this.

I changed `unowned` reference to `weak` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> which means that it holds a strong reference back to the RetainCycle instance

This isn't true. It has an unowned reference back to the RetainCycle instance. That's not the same thing as a strong reference.

> But I want to understand which scenario both will not be mutually deallocated at the same time and Unowned self becomes nilI just want to crash it.?

Any time `closure` is captured by something outside of `RetainCycle`, and so outlives its owner:

```
var rc: RetainCycle? = RetainCycle()   // create an RC

let cl = rc?.closure  // Hold onto its closure

rc = nil // Deallocate the RC

cl?() // Access the closure safely, but its reference to `self` is invalid. Crash.
```

As a rule, closures that involve `unowned self` should be impossible to reference outside of `self`. It's sometimes difficult to know this is true. For example, here is a case that recently crashed an app I work on:

```
var completion: (() -> Void)?

...

DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
    self.completion()
    self.completion = nil
}
```

This feels fine, but if `self` is deallocated between the time it enqueues the main-queue block and the time that block runs, boom.

BTW, in this case the right answer would be a regular, strong `self`. We *want* the retain loop to keep this object around until its completion handler runs, at which point the block goes away, the reference to `self` goes away, and `self` is properly deallocated. So `[weak self]` is not always the answer, either.